# Prolog:get the head of the list who contains the most common elements

Tags: list, prolog

I'm doing the game akinator in prolog

So I have a list that I fill in with words, I call it Description
and i have a database which i put as list list:

```
characters([[napoleon, real, politician, man, european, dead],
            [trump, man, real, politician, blond, american, alive],
            [zidane, man, real, footballer, european, alive],
            [tupac, man, real, rapper, american, dead],
            [hercules, man, hero, adventurer, young, dead],
            [mermaid, fictional, woman, dead]]).
```

Suppose that
`Description = [real, politician, europpen, man]`
I would like to find precisely the corresponding name which is in my list of characters list, knowing that in each sub-list its head corresponds to the name

```
% counts number of elements in a list
account([], 0).

count([_ | R], N) :-
    count(R, N1),
    N is N1 + 1,
    N > 0.

search([], [], 0, _).
search([[T | Q2] | Q], Input, Nbcommons, T): -
    intersection(Q2, Input, R),
    account(R, N),
    (   N >= Nbcommons
    ->  search(Q, Input, N, Head)
    ;   search(Q, Input, Nbcommons, T)
    ).
```

The idea would therefore be to intersect the rest of the list with my Descritpion list, to count the number of common elements then to keep the list of the database having the most common elements and then return its head corresponding to the name
But it's fail ... it return "out of pile stack"

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please edit your question and add exactly what query you are running.

Answer (score 0):

I see is a typo problem: line 1 is defining account/2 and the next line is defining count/2. The relation count([a,b,c], N) invokes itself recursively without the end condition in line 1. This may explain the pile problem, depending on your Prolog.

The count program can be written more efficiently (tail end recursion optimization) as:

```
count(L, N) :- count(L, 0, N).

    count([], N, N).
    count([_|Rest], Cur, N) :- N1 is Cur+1, count(Rest, N1, N).
```